# React redux dispatch not available

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-thunk

Originally I had this call at `index.js` to trigger the load of my main data:

```
const store = configureStore();
store.dispatch(doStuff());
```

Now I want to do the next step and load this data at page level (seems better).

---

I'm basing myself on this post by Gaearon at the [Redux github](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/916):

[image]

---

I have this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as myActions from '../../actions/myActions';
import { MuiThemeProvider } from 'material-ui/styles';

let createHandlers = function(dispatch) {
    let doStuff = function() {
      dispatch(myActions.doStuff())
    };

    return {
        doStuff,
      // other handlers
    };
  }


class MyPage extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.handlers = createHandlers(this.props.dispatch);
        //this.handlers.doStuff();

        this.state = {
            myStuff: []
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div>...</div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        // Set state
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        // Set state
    };
}

MyPage.propTypes = {
        // My props
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyPage);
```

---

**The issue**

When I uncomment the line, I get this error:

> TypeError: dispatch is not a function

```
let doStuff = function() {  
   dispatch(myActions.doStuff()) 
};
```

The (most important) difference that I see is that I do mapping:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyPage);
```

What do I need to do to get this to work?

*Likely something easy, but I don't see it.*

Comment: https://github.com/kalaikt/reactjs/blob/master/src/js/view/profile/medallion/report-problem.js I hope this may help you

Comment: Why don't you do all your `dispatch()` calls inside your `mapDispatchToProps`? Do you really need to call dispatch inside your component (which is different to in the same file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy ... I didn't need Gaearon's script at all. All I had to do is call the actions list from the constructor:

```
class MyPage extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        props.actions.doStuff();

        this.state = {
            myStuff: []
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div>...</div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

Where this is the important line:

```
props.actions.doStuff();
```

Which is available because it's mapped in `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(loadOrderActions, dispatch)
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Connect's react-redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) explain that:

> If you do not supply your own mapDispatchToProps function or object
>   full of action creators, the default mapDispatchToProps implementation
>   just injects dispatch into your component’s props.

When you don't pass `mapDispatchToProps` params to `connect`, react-redux passes `dispatch` as a prop to the wrapped component.

If you pass `mapDispatchToProps` to `connect`, the wrapped actions are passed instead of `dispatch`, and `this.props.dispatch` is undefined.

So if you need `dispatch` in your compon, refrain from using `mapDispatchToProps`, or wrap all your actions with `dispatch` inside `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: I do want the `mapDispatchToProps` method, because that's how I update my state. So, what's the solution?

Comment: The solution is to wrap you action with `dispatch` in `mapDispatchToProps`.